# Jboss drools: Memory leak when using accumulate collectList function

Tags: apache-spark, jboss, spark-streaming, drools

I am using jboss drools to execute rules on spark big data platform.
I am using the accumulate function in "when" (lhs) to collect objects matching the condition.
This works for cases where the list size is small.
However, for one of my cases, I have 25000 matches for a condition.
So the collectList should have 25000 items. This does not work.

When I checked the logs, I see a full GC being done and the job gets stuck there.
Please can you help me out here. Any alternatives to get this working would be good.

I tried increasing the executor memory with no luck.

Example of my rule:

```
rule "Get people by name Alfredo , age 55" salience 1

    when
       accumulate($p: Person(name == "Alfredo", age == 55);
       $personList: collectList( $p ), $cnt: count($p); $cnt>0)
    then
       CREATE_PERSON_RESULT(kcontext, MIN($personList, "name"))
    end
```

Thanks,

Pranoti

Comment: any exception messages found ? if so can you paste full stack here?

Comment: workaround: if I understood correctly your CREATE_PERSON_RESULT takes just 1 name, right? why don't you accumulate min() instead of the list in LHS?

Comment: Why do you collect the List? Do you really need them all in one List?

Comment: @laune: Yes I need all the records matching the condition in a list. I have a set of selector operators which selects the best record from the list. The above MIN("name") is an example. I have rules which can select Min/Max of any attribute of Person objects.

Comment: @jfneis: It creates 1 in the example above. As another example, the below code would return Alfredo person with minimum age (could be more than 1): rule "Get people by name Alfredo , age 55" salience 1

    when
       accumulate($p: Person(name == "Alfredo");
       $personList: collectList( $p ), $cnt: count($p); $cnt>0)
    then
       CREATE_PERSON_RESULT(kcontext, MIN($personList, "age"))
    end

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram: There is no exception. Full GC occurs where spark is trying to probably allocate space for the big list. Please find logs below: **[PSYoungGen: 4660736K->2330112K(4660736K)] 12525953K->12548341K(16179200K), 4.0982140 secs] [Times: user=28.54 sys=30.54, real=4.09 secs] 
135.512: [Full GC147.832: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000430 secs]147.832: [WeakReference, 1069 refs, 0.0002630 secs]147.833: [FinalReference, 630 refs, 0.0000700 secs]147.833: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 28 refs, 0.0000200 secs]147.833: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000370 secs].**

Comment: Any help here will be appreciated. I just need a list of all the facts that have matched a condition so I could apply some filters (based on filter functions in then(RHS) without hitting the memory. Any workaround here also will be good.

Comment: @pranoti but whatever you need to in LHS. Is there any rule where you return a list?

Comment: @jfneis: $personList will be the collected list from LHS. The CREATE_PERSON_RESULT will create a list fo person objects after applying the filters.

Comment: You are not using Drools right. If you need a filter, why not put the filter in the rule? If you need a minimum, you don't need accumulate. - It would be better to describe your problem that to state the problems you have with your solution.

Comment: @laune: Sorry for not being clear. I have a dataset of Person objects having fields like name, age, address, phone, last_updated. I have a set of rules that applies on this dataset. An example would be, give me all persons whose name is Alfredo. Another could be, give me all persons whose name is alfredo (say there are 10 alfredo's) and with minimum age(say of the 10 , 5 are of age 30) and last_updated to be latest (of the 5 select all records with latest timestamp. So my selectors in then would look like: MAX(MIN("age"), "timestamp") (-can be nested further) for the list of alfredos in When.

Comment: @laune: I was collecting all to a list so I could apply the nested filters. Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Comment: @pranotishanbhag creating a custom accumulate function that compares your MIN/MAX attributes and let go objects that do not satisfy the MIN/MAX would, in theory, be a more efficient solution in terms of memory usage. http://blog.athico.com/2007/06/accumulate-functions-edson-tirelli.html